# OpenCV Stereo Calibration of IR-Cameras

Tags: opencv, tracking, camera-calibration, calibration, infrared

I have 2 webcams with removed IR blocking filters and applied visible light blocking filters. Thus, both cameras can only see IR light. So I can not calibrate the stereo cameras by oberserving points on a chessboard (because I don't see the chessboard). Instead of this I had the idea to use some amount of IR-LEDs as a tracking pattern. I could attach the LEDs on some chessboard, for instance. AFAIK, the OpenCV `stereoCalibrate` function awaits the `objectPoints`, as well as the `imagePoints1` and `imagePoints2` and will return both camera matrices, distortion coeffs as well as the fundamental matrix.

How many points in my images do I need to detect in order to get the function running appropriate? For the fundamental matrix I know the eight-point algorithm. So, are 8 points enough? The problem is, I don't want to use a huge amount of IR-LEDs as a tracking pattern.
Are there some better ways to do so?

Comment: Of course it is related to programming even if there is no code to at the moment. I am talking about the correct usage of the OpenCV stereoCalibrate() method.

Answer (score 0):

Why not remove the filters, calibrate and then replace them?

(For pure curiosities sake what are you working on?)